# remove file from zsh autocomplete

Tags: zsh

if I type

```
vim pack
```

and hit tab zsh autocompletes to `package-lock.json`, but 10 times out of 10 I would rather it complete to `package.json` as the first option.

How can I either:

- make it autocomplete to `package.json` first
- stop it completing `package-lock.json` at all

Comment: I think you want `compctl -D -f -tn`, but `man zshcompctl` if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Zsh's "new" completion system (that is, the one released in the year 2000, which you need to initialize with `autoload -Uz compinit; compinit`) —and you should— then the following will work:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' ignored-patterns 'package-lock.json'
```

Documentation: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-ignored_002dpatterns_002c-completion-style